# What is the reason for this x86 calling convention?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, llvm-clang

I was trying to reduce the clutter in my original question (below), but I am afraid that made it harder to follow. So here is the original source along with IDA's disassembly.

My question still is this: why does getStruct() pop the return argument and only the return argument off the stack? (It's calling ret 4 instead of ret for no arguments or ret 12 for all three arguments).

```
#include <iostream>
struct SomeStruct {
    char m_buff[0x1000];
};

SomeStruct getStruct(uint32_t someArg1, uint32_t someArg2)
{
    return SomeStruct();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    SomeStruct myLocalStruct = getStruct(0x20,0x30);

    return 0;
}

; _DWORD __stdcall getStruct(unsigned int, unsigned int)
                public getStruct(unsigned int, unsigned int)
getStruct(unsigned int, unsigned int) proc near ; CODE XREF: _main+4Dp

var_8           = dword ptr -8
var_4           = dword ptr -4
arg_0           = dword ptr  8
arg_4           = dword ptr  0Ch
arg_8           = dword ptr  10h

                push    ebp
                mov     ebp, esp
                sub     esp, 18h
                mov     eax, [ebp+arg_8]
                mov     ecx, [ebp+arg_4]
                mov     edx, [ebp+arg_0]
                mov     [ebp+var_4], ecx
                mov     [ebp+var_8], eax
                mov     eax, esp
                mov     [eax], edx
                mov     dword ptr [eax+4], 1000h
                call    ___bzero
                add     esp, 18h
                pop     ebp
                retn    4
getStruct(unsigned int, unsigned int) endp

; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                align 10h

; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================

; Attributes: bp-based frame

; int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
                public _main
_main           proc near

var_1020        = dword ptr -1020h
var_101C        = dword ptr -101Ch
var_1018        = dword ptr -1018h
var_14          = dword ptr -14h
var_10          = dword ptr -10h
var_C           = dword ptr -0Ch
argc            = dword ptr  8
argv            = dword ptr  0Ch
envp            = dword ptr  10h

                push    ebp
                mov     ebp, esp
                push    edi
                push    esi
                sub     esp, 1030h
                mov     eax, [ebp+argv]
                mov     ecx, [ebp+argc]
                lea     edx, [ebp+var_1018]
                mov     esi, 20h
                mov     edi, 30h
                mov     [ebp+var_C], 0
                mov     [ebp+var_10], ecx
                mov     [ebp+var_14], eax
                mov     [esp], edx      ; ptr to destination
                mov     dword ptr [esp+4], 20h ; unsigned int
                mov     dword ptr [esp+8], 30h
                mov     [ebp+var_101C], esi
                mov     [ebp+var_1020], edi
                call    getStruct(uint,uint)
                sub     esp, 4
                mov     eax, 0
                add     esp, 1030h
                pop     esi
                pop     edi
                pop     ebp
                retn
_main           endp
```

***Original question below:***

I have some function with the following declaration:

```
SomeStruct getStruct(uint32_t someArg1, uint32_t someArg2);
```

getStruct is being called like this:

```
myLocalStruct = getStruct(someArg1,someArg2);
```

When compiling this using clang on x86 the calling code looks roughly like this:

```
lea esi, [ebp-myLocalStructOffset] 
mov [esp], esi
mov [esp+4], someArg1
mov [esp+8], someArg2
call getStruct;
sub esp, 4;
```

So the caller is restoring its stack pointer after the call. Sure enough, the implementation of getStruct ends with a ret 4, effectively popping the structs pointer.

This looks like it is partially cdecl with the caller being responsible for the stack cleanup, and partially stdcall with the callee removing the arguments. I just cannot figure out what the reason is for this approach. Why not leave all the cleanup to the caller? Is there any benefit to this ?

Comment: Are you using x86 or x86_64?

Comment: There are 12 bytes being put on the stack, but only 8 bytes are being popped? Are you sure about that? The callee should be using `ret 8` instead.  It is a little odd that the stack cleanup is being split between caller and callee, though. Maybe it is related to [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)?

Comment: Note that sub esp,4 is allocating 4 bytes from the stack, it's not restoring the stack. Restoring the stack after a call uses an add, not a subtract instruction. It appears that esp is changed to point to the local structure (so ebp will be needed later on to restore esp), and that after getStruct returns, the sub esp,4 will point esp back to the local structure.

Comment: As pointed out by rcgldr, the `sub` is an allocation, not a pop. It seems much more plausible that this instruction is not part of the `getStruct` call, but that it is the start of a subsequent C command instead. You may want to use a debugger to track the stack pointer (compare the stack size before/after the call), rather than speculate about it.

Comment: @Ruud: Indeed. I assume that there is a similar `sub esp,12` somewhere above but it was not quoted in this question. The `sub esp, 4` is very likely the allocation for the next function call. The calling convention looks like it could be stdcall, and the return value is passed as an extra pointer argument.

Comment: IOW, the compiler compiles this as `void getStruct(SomeStruct *returnValue, unit32_t someArg1, unt32_t someArg2);`.

Comment: My previous comment should have been that [esp] is changed to point to the local structure. As mentioned, the original example didn't include what was probably a sub esp,12 before the shown code. The compiler will eventually produce code to restore esp with an add as needed, or restore it from ebp, since it appears that ebp is being used as a frame pointer.

Comment: Sorry about the missing lines. Complete code is now listed.
@Remy: callee pops 4 bytes, caller then promptly undoes this change by doing a sub esp,4

Comment: Assuming this is a single source file, then it's possible that some type of global optimization resulted in the called function using a retn 4, followed by the main code's sub esp,4 to restore esp back to it's previous state before the call. Note that an add esp,1030h is being used to restore esp in main, as opposed to restoring it from ebp, so there needed to be a correction to esp to restore it to it's  state before the call to getstruct.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you forgot to quote the few lines of assembler above the part you quoted. I assume there is something like:

```
sub esp,12
```

somewhere above what you quoted. The calling convention looks like pure `stdcall`, and the return value is in reality passed as a hidden pointer argument, i.e. the code is in fact *compiled* as if you had declared:

```
void __stdcall getStruct(SomeStruct *returnValue, uint32_t someArg1, uint32_t someArg2);
```

Comment: Thank you, Rudy. Perhaps I am ignorant about stdcall then. I thought stdcall means the callee is responsible for cleaning up ALL the arguments. I.e. popping returnValue, someArg1, and someArg2 ? But the code only pops the first 4 bytes instead of all 12.

Comment: In `stdcall`, the callee is responsible for cleanup, not the caller. The `sub esp,4` has, as far as I can see, nothing to do with the call to `getStruct` anymore. `sub esp,4` ***is not stack cleanup***. It probably reserves stack memory for the following function call, i.e. the line below the call to `getStruct`, which seems to have one argument.

Comment: I just saw your edits. I currently have no idea why the code for getStruct is like it is, and I don't have the time to investigate what is going on, sorry.